# JavaScript: How to parse the named anchor from the href of a link?

Tags: javascript

I would like to parse the named anchor from the href of a link when it is clicked. How can this be done?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.my-links').click(function(e){
        var href = this.href; // http://example.com#myNamedAnchor
        // now parse out just 'myNamedAnchor'
    });
});
```

Comment: var s = "http://example.com#myNamedAnchor";

var parts = s.split('#');
var hash;

if (parts.length > 1) {
  hash = parts[1];
}

hash ; //# =>  myNamedAnchor

Comment: I don't think any of your answers so far (except for the one in the comment above I think) account for URLs that **don't** happen to have an anchor suffix.  You may want to clarify whether that's important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the anchor with `this.hash`. To strip out the `#`, use `this.hash.substr(1)`.

```
$('.my-links').click(function(e){
    var hash = this.hash.substr(1); // myNamedAnchor
});
```

[See the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLAnchorElement).

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.my-links').click(function(e){
        var href = this.href; // http://example.com#myNamedAnchor
        var hash = href.substr(href.indexOf('#'));
        alert(hash);
        return false;
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aQcSk/).

If you don't want to include the `#` character, then amend the above to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.my-links').click(function(e){
        var href = this.href; // http://example.com#myNamedAnchor
        var hash = href.substr(href.indexOf('#') + 1);
        alert(hash);
        return false;
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aQcSk/1/).

References:

- [`substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).
- [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Comment: Will print it out along with the `#` use `+1` to get rid of it :)

Comment: I know, I was editing that in as you added the comment (it was within the grace period, at least...). But thank you for the catch! =D

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.my-links').click(function(e){
        var href = this.href; // http://example.com#myNamedAnchor
        var myNamedAnchor = href.match(/[^#]*$/);
    });
});
```

That'll do it.

Comment: Why the regex? `substr` and `indexOf` are 100% sufficient.

Comment: Well, I guess it's a valid, albeit complicated, alternative...and it expands the options at least.

Comment: I like it because it's non-complicated O_o what's simpler than `/[^#]*$/`? (!)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do:

```
$('.my-links').click(function(e){
     //if  http://example.com#myNamedAnchor hash = myNamedAnchor 
     var hash=this.hash;        
});
```

Comment: it has to load first though.  This is in the click event so the poster is trying to catch it before the request is sent.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
parsedHref = href.substr(href.indexOf("#")+1);
```

To find whatever is after the hash.